# How to design GridView to display with scrolling

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

How to design GridView in such a way that it display 3 images per row and can be scrolled up for the other Images behind? it seems this gridView displays images in a row.

Below I have 8 Pic in Gridview:

1) How to setup GridView to displays images with(3 images per row)  or without specifying number of images per row and the rest will be viewed by scrolling up?

Thanks

```
 < GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,200,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Height="400"  >


//-- pic 1

 < GridViewItem>

   < Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="200">
     < Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">

      < Image  Source="Images/M123.jpg" Tag="name" Tapped="Image_Tapped_1" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

     < /Border>
     < StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     < TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="name" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="40" Margin="15,10,15,0"/>
     </StackPanel>

     </Grid>
 </GridViewItem>


//- pic 2 using GridViewItem


//-- pic 3 using GridViewItem


//--- Pic 3 to Pic 8 GridViewItem



 < / GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the grid view in a scrollviewer and let the height of the gridview be auto ie it will take the height of the entire content and width of the grid view to a specific one so that t cqn take only 3 items

next step is to just enable the vertical scroll property of the scroll viewer and disable the horizontal scroll property.

i hope this solves the purpose .

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working. using your scrollviewer instruction, it displays images in vertical manner.

Comment: Please set the min width and max width of the grid view and the scrollviewer to same and  to so extent .. since you have got the vertical scrolling just play with the width of it i guess it might work

Answer (score 0):

try to use jquery plugin 
http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

```
 function gridviewScroll() { 
    $('#<%=gvMain.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({ 
        width: 700, 
        height: 330, 
        freezesize: 2, 
        arrowsize: 30, 
        varrowtopimg: "Images/arrowvt.png", 
        varrowbottomimg: "Images/arrowvb.png", 
        harrowleftimg: "Images/arrowhl.png", 
        harrowrightimg: "Images/arrowhr.png", 
        headerrowcount: 2 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I need to use C# in WinRT.  Thanks

Comment: i not sure if this on Gridview properties but you can make it with css